# What's the name of the board game with dinosaur cards?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember having and playing this game in early to late 90's when I was a kid. There was a deck of dinosaurs with stats like "length", "ferocity", and two others I cannot remember. When you finished your turn on one of four special fields which were located in the corners of the board, you'd have put down one of your dinosaur cards and compare the specified stat with other player(s) cards. I faintly remember that whenever you would win, you would move your other indicator away from the volcano which was pictured in the middle of the board. HELP!

Comment: The timeframe is off, but Evo (2001; 2nd edition in 2011) has many of the features you describe. Likely inspired by your game; potentially an alternative if you have trouble sourcing the game you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Lost Valley of the Dinosaurs](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3149/lost-valley-dinosaurs)? While technically published in 1985, it could easily have been a staple in the '90s.

The description from BoardGameGeek:

> You have discovered an ancient chart to a lost valley. It shows that once the valley was occupied by a fierce tribe of natives who had collected a vast wealth of treasure and used vicious dinosaurs to help protect it.
>
> No humans inhabit the valley now and the chart shows that the 'treasure' is still hidden in a temple at the top of the valley but the dinosaurs are still there!
>
> The secret of the valley and its treasure have been stolen and you know that other expeditions are currently journeying to discover the lost secret of the valley.
>
> As your party enters the valley a volcano which has been dormant for centuries rumbles and threatens to engulf the valley in lava.
>
> The race is on, who will win the fabulous riches of the temple and who may die?

It appears to use "Adventure Cards", and involves the adventurers being chased around the board by dinosaurs while collecting treasure.

Comment: I have Lost Valley of the Dinosaurs, and, while they both feature dinosaurs, can confirm that the game described above is not it, since none of the other mechanics the OP mentioned are present in LVofD.

Answer (score 1):

From www.spotlightongames.com

Return of the Dinosaurs 
(unknown); Spear's Games-1992; 2-4; 20 
A double-sided board affords two different games. Escape from the Volcano is a roll-and-move game. The challenge spaces trigger a contest among the players. Whoever plays the card having the higher value in the chosen category gets to move one space further away from the soon-to-erupt volcano. The first to reach the tenth space wins. The Dinosaur Dig is a roll-and-move game of collecting pieces to build up a dinosaur. A dig space permits drawing a dinosaur piece card. The first to collect all four pieces wins. Cards contain a number of facts about dinosaurs.

Comment: This is undoubtedly correct. The stats are Period, Age, Weight, Length, Ferocity and Diet.